# Custom type showing "Module not found" error in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

## Edit 2

#### nav-bar.component.ts

```
...
import { ILink } from '../nav-bar';
...
```

#### nav-bar-link.component.ts

```
...
import { ILink } from '../../nav-bar';
...
```

## Edit 1

I'm using Webstorm which recognizes the type when I use it in nav-bar-link.component.ts and by recognize I mean that if I control-click the type it takes me to the definition file.  I am using ng build to compile all of it which is also using the following tsconfig.json.

#### tsconfig.json

```
{  
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "",
        "declaration": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2016",
            "dom"
        ],
        "mapRoot": "./",
        "module": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
            "../node_modules/@types"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "main.ts",
        "polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "**/client/**/*.ts",
        "**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

I have tried creating a typings folder with an index.d.ts in it with all the interfaces that I've created but even then the nav-bar-link component will give the same error as originally described.

## Original Post

I am trying to share the type definition files between the server and client and so I've set the definition file above the client and server files.  I am importing the type definition into both angular components but the nav-bar-link throws this error.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/nav-bar/client/link/nav-bar-link.component.ts  
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../nav-bar' in 'D:\example-app\src\app\nav-bar\client\link'  
@ ./src/app/nav-bar/client/link/nav-bar-link.component.ts 11:0-38  
@ ./src/app/app.module.ts  
@ ./src/main.  
@ multi ./src/main.ts
```

#### Folder Structure

- nav-bar/

  - nav-bar.d.ts
  - server/
  - client/

    - nav-bar.component.ts
    - nav-bar.component.html
    - nav-bar.component.scss
    - link/

      - nav-bar-link.component.ts
      - nav-bar-link.component.html
      - nav-bar-link.component.scss

#### nav-bar.d.ts

```
export interface ILink {
    title: string;
    ...
}
```

I have tried moving nav-bar-link into a separate "module", so in a sibling folder to nav-bar, and it still throws the same error when I try to import ILink.

How can I use that interface in both components without throwing that error?

Comment: Can you provide some more details about your environment? Are you using angular cli, what IDE, any other info ect..

Comment: Off the top of my head, not fully knowing your environment it looks like you may need to include some references to your interfaces. Possibly using barrels (index.ts). Or by including your types via tsconfig.json. http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: What it seems like from the given picture is, you have not given the `absolute path` for the said Module.

Comment: @Haroon I just added the import statements for those components including that definition file.  I don't understand what you mean by absolute path, do you mean in those components? Or the tsconfig.json file?

Comment: sorry I meant `relative path` in your import statement.
Def: 
A relative path is a way to specify the location of a directory relative to another directory.  For example, suppose your documents are in C:\Sample\Documents and your index is in C:\Sample\Index.  The absolute path for the documents would be C:\Sample\Documents.  The relative path from C:\Sample\Index to C:\Sample\Documents would be ..\Documents.